# AndroidManifest.xml notification icon not found

Tags: android, flutter

I have a transparent/white icon located here in my Flutter project:
#PROJECT#/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/android_notification_icon.png

And in my AndroidManifest.xml I have this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/android_notification_icon.png" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/notificationIconColor" />
```

But I am getting this error:
AndroidManifest.xml:55: AAPT: error: resource drawable/android_notification_icon.png (aka dk.myapp.debug:drawable/android_notification_icon.png) not found.

Why can my android_notification_icon.png not be found?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: `android:resource="@drawable/android_notification_icon"`

Comment: Make sure your png is proper or not

Comment: omg yes, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> AndroidManifest.xml:55: AAPT: error: resource
> drawable/android_notification_icon.png (aka
> dk.myapp.debug:drawable/android_notification_icon.png) not found.

You should use

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/android_notification_icon" />
```

You can add below in your **`build.gradle`** section.

```
android {
...
  aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
  }
....
}
```

This will turn off the **`AAPT`** png optimization for any non-9patch PNG files inside of your APK.

Finally **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: Where do you add... 

aaptOptions {
   cruncherEnabled = false
}

It's not XML so I don't think it goes in AndroidManifest... where should I put this?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign In your `build.gradle` section.